# How to get client certificate properties on aiohttp server

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, openssl, aiohttp

I have a problem with getting client certificate properties on aiohttp server. I use session because on real server I use websockets. Here you can see example of server and client. Please tell me how to get client certificate on aiohttp server inside of hello function.

Example of server.py

```
import os
import ssl

async def hello(request):
    cert = request.transport.get_extra_info("peercert") # return None

    # I want to get client certificate properties here

    return web.Response(text="Hello world")

def create_ssl_context_server():
    ssl_cntx = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)
    localhost_pem = os.path.abspath(os.environ["CERT_PATH"])
    private_key = os.path.abspath(os.environ["KEY_PATH"])
    ssl_cntx.load_cert_chain(
        certfile=localhost_pem,
        keyfile=private_key,
    )
    ssl_cntx.ski = cert_file_ski_validate(localhost_pem)  # type: ignore
    ssl_cntx.self_signed = int(self_signed)  # type: ignore
    return ssl_cntx

def create_app():

    app = aiohttp.web.Application()
    app.router.add_route("GET", "/hello", hello)

    return app

if __name__ == "__main__":

    ssl_context_server = create_ssl_context_server()
    app = create_app()

    web.run_app(app, ssl_context=ssl_context_server)
```

example of client.py

```
import ssl
import aiohttp
import asyncio


def client_session(url):
    ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
    ssl_context.load_cert_chain(
        certfile="<path to client cert.pem>",
        keyfile="<path to client key.pem>"
    )

    session = aiohttp.ClientSession(
            base_url=f"https://{url}",
            connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(ssl=ssl_context, force_close=True, enable_cleanup_closed=True),
        )
    return session


async def main():
    session = client_session("localhost:8000")

    async with session.get('/hello') as response:

        if response.status == 200:
            rtxt = await response.text()

            print(rtxt)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```